# Does a steady state exist for a looped flow network which allows negative flow?

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains, network-flow, steady-state

I am modelling something with a flow network.

- There are a number of layers to the network, each layer has a different number of nodes.
- Each node receives some flow from all the nodes in the previous layer, and splits its output into nodes in the next layer.
- The final layer output loops back into the first layer.

I believe (although I currently do not have rigorous proof) that such a steady state exists for such a network... when all the flows are positive.

But actually, this model allows any node to "suck" flow backwards -- the flow rate between two such nodes is a negative number.

**Does a steady state exist for such a network?**

(The flow through each node in a layer can be calculated by constructing a suitable matrix and multiplying the previous layer by that matrix. I believe this means the problem is equivalent to finding an eigenvector; assuming that flows have been properly normalised, the eigenvalue will be 1. In which case I need to prove that this solution exists, but now I'm stuck.)

Comment: When we study a "flow network" (more commonly, a "network flow"), it is usually specified that there is a source and a sink that drives the flow (sometimes more than one of both).  At the same time edges of the graph are usually assigned "capacities" so that the flow between adjacent nodes is thus limited.  Introducing "backward flow" seems to contradict your arrangement of nodes into layers of the network, since by your description, "Each node receives some flow from all the nodes in the previous  layer, and splits its output into nodes in the next layer."  Perhaps an example will clarify?